# Python - Storing output of renamed files to a variable

Tags: python

I have a list of files in a folder that I am trying to rename (by extension) and then have them appended together as a single file.

The below code helps me to rename the file by extension:

```
for filename in allFiles:
    ##allFiles is path where the files are located
    if filename.endswith(".doc"):
        os.rename(filename, filename[:-4])
```

I am trying to see if I can have the above stored to a variable so that I can refer the variable in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply store filenames in a list:

```
renamed = []
for filename in allFiles:
    ##allFiles is path where the files are located
    if filename.endswith(".doc"):
        os.rename(filename, filename[:-4])
        renamed.append(filename[:-4])
```